# Python - PANDAS - Create new dataframe by processing data, preserving multiple old indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I have a `csv` data file that I've read into a dataframe:

```
## Read the CSV data file into a data frame using PANDAS
fileAll = '../Data/05_FranckHertz_LabProData_AllTemps_UpDn.csv'
AllData = pd.read_csv(fileAll, sep=',', header=0, index_col=[0,1])
```

The data consist of voltage and current measurements at six different temperatures while increasing or decreasing the voltage. The temperature (`Temp`) and direction (`Dir` - either up or down) are used as indices.

The data are read in and then converted:

```
slope_Va, int_Va = (-19.096514967, -0.3912355461)
slope_Ic, int_Ic = ( -0.333075600, -0.0201979916)
AllData['Va'] = (slope_Va * AllData.Pot1) + int_Va  ## Add column for Va
AllData['Ic'] = (slope_Ic * AllData.Pot2) + int_Ic  ## Add column for Ic
```

Now, these converted values need to be smoothed out, and it's those smoothed results that I would like to put in a new dataframe. ***But*** I need to preserve the original indices. The smoothing process removes some of the data, so the routine outputs an `ndarray` that is shorter than the input data.

I've been looking around StackExchange all day, and even got a discussion going on Reddit, but to no avail.

My code is currently located at https://github.com/bgcamroux/PHYS297. The data are in the file named `05_FranckHertz*.csv` and the main script I'm working on is `02_FranckHertz_Method1.py`. The smoothing function is located in `BGCprocLib.py`.

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is too simple, but taking `df` to be your `DataFrame`, why not do `df2 = df.copy()`, run your smoothing ops on the copy, and then assign the data in the copy back to the original `DataFrame`? If you do so `pandas` should align the indices for you automatically.

Comment: @ResMar: Oh, I never thought of that. Simple solutions are most certainly welcome! I'll give that a try and see. I don't know PANDAS (or even Python) very well yet, so I didn't know `df.copy()` was even an option.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to smooth each temperature and direction separately, as I don't want there to be any inter-mixing between them.

Comment: @ResMar: Okay I tried that and I get the error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4,), indices imply (4,88463)`.

Comment: It sounds like you're not merging them properly. Try taking a column out of `df2` that you're interested in and assigning it to your original `df`. So e.g. `df['something'] = df2['something']`. Does that work?